# ExceptionFilterAttribute .net core

Tags: asp.net-core

There is an example of how to make a CustomExceptionFilterAttribute at https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html
I would like to do the same to make a CustomExceptionFilterAttribute with IHostingEnvironment as the parameter.

```
services.AddMvc(
        config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(???));
        });
```

I am trying to add filters in startup class, but I don't know how to supply the IHostingEnvironment parameter.

services.AddMvc has to be in method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

I got error if I do

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services,IHostingEnvironment env)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Startup` constructor injection like this:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _env = env;
}
```

.....

```
services.AddMvc(
    config =>
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(_env));
    });
```

See official docs https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/startup.html#services-available-in-startup

Comment: yeah....I haven't realized that I could inject to the startup class like any other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would want to implement is [IExceptionFilter Interface](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Mvc/Filters/IExceptionFilter/index.html), and after implementation you can add some CustomExceptionFilter into ConfigureServices. CustomExceptionFilterAttribute need to be dealt with differently, because that is an Attribute.